# Add and remove elements class on ViewChild in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, tabs, materialize, viewchild

I have tabs in my application, the active tab must correspond to the user's level. I created a viewChild to add its active class but I was unsuccessful, and the following error appears:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelector' of undefined
    at TrainingComponent.push../src/app/views/training/training.component.ts.TrainingComponent.ngAfterViewInit
```

**My component:**

```
  @ViewChild('tabExplorator') tabExplorator: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('tabEspecialist') tabEspecialist: ElementRef;

  constructor(public timeguard:TimeguardService, public router: Router,  public progressbar:ProgressBarService, public geo: GeolocationService, public dl: DatalayerService<GameDimensionSet>, public database: DatabaseService < Fase > , public auth: AuthService) {}

  ngAfterViewInit () {
    //assigning an element to a variable
    let tabExplorator = this.tabExplorator.nativeElement.querySelector('tabExplorator')
    let tabEspecialist = this.tabEspecialist.nativeElement.querySelector('tabEspecialist')

    if(this.auth.User.nivel == 'EXPLORADOR' && tabExplorator.classList.contains('active')){
      tabExplorator.classList.remove('active')
      tabEspecialist.classList.add('active')
    }

  }
```

**My HTML:**

```
 <ul class="tabs ranking-letra-tabs tabs-icon">
      <li class="tab col s3 cor-explorador alinha-texto">
        <a href="#ranking-nivel1" #tabExplorator>
          <div>
            <i class="material-icons cor-estrelas tabs-icon">star</i>
          </div>
          <div class="">
            {{NIVEL1}}
          </div>
        </a>
      </li>

      <li class="tab col s3 cor-especialista alinha-texto">
        <a href="#ranking-nivel2" #tabEspecialist>
          <div>
            <i class="material-icons cor-estrelas estrela-tabs-1">star</i>
            <i class="material-icons cor-estrelas estrela-tabs-2">star</i>
          </div>
          <div>
            {{NIVEL2}}
          </div>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

I'm using materialize, according to the documentation:

"Show tab content that corresponds to the tab with the id"

```
instance.select('tab_id');
```

Could that help?

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`Renderer2`](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2) along with the `ElementRef` to toggle element classes. It uses Renderer's [`addClass()`](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2#addClass) and [`removeClass()`](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2#removeClass) functions based on if the element contains the `active` class. The boolean denoting the current state is obtained using [`element.classList.contains('active')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/contains) function. Try the following

```js
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  @ViewChild('tabExplorator') tabExplorator: ElementRef;

  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) { }

  toggleBackground() {
    const active = this.tabExplorator.nativeElement.classList.contains('active');

    this.renderer[active ? 'removeClass' : 'addClass'](this.tabExplorator.nativeElement, 'active');
  }
}
```

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-scnjyc)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you read a little about [ngClass](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass) for add or remove class in element with expressions. In your code, I would write a code like:

```
 <ul class="tabs ranking-letra-tabs tabs-icon">
  <li class="tab col s3 cor-explorador alinha-texto">
    <a href="#ranking-nivel1" [class.active]="isUserExplorer">
      <div>
        <i class="material-icons cor-estrelas tabs-icon">star</i>
      </div>
      <div class="">
        {{NIVEL1}}
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>

  <li class="tab col s3 cor-especialista alinha-texto">
    <a href="#ranking-nivel2" [class.active]="!isUserExplorer">
      <div>
        <i class="material-icons cor-estrelas estrela-tabs-1">star</i>
        <i class="material-icons cor-estrelas estrela-tabs-2">star</i>
      </div>
      <div>
        {{NIVEL2}}
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Adapting the logic that you need in 'isUserExplorer', and in your typescript code:

```
get isUserExplorer(): boolean { return this.auth.User.nivel === 'EXPLORADOR'; }

constructor(public timeguard:TimeguardService, public router: Router,  public progressbar:ProgressBarService, public geo: GeolocationService, public dl: DatalayerService<GameDimensionSet>, public database: DatabaseService < Fase > , public auth: AuthService) {}
```

I recommend you not use @ViewChild for prevent encapsulation violation of the elements.
In the [style guide](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide) you can view [class.syntax] and other hacks for have a beautiful code xd

I hope it helps